# Result calculation in rod cutting

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, clrs

I am learning the rod cutting algorithm from CLRS book.

I believe I understand the logic and my below solution was accepted on [this](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rod-cutting/0) OJ.

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int prices[101];
int result[101];

int function(int length)
{

    if (length == 0)
        return 0;    

    if (result[length] != INT_MIN)
    {
        return result[length];
    }

    //calculate result for length
    //if cutting the rod is more profitable, this variable will get overwritten in the loop below
    int current_max = prices[length];

    for (int cut_size = 1; cut_size < length; cut_size++)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        a = function(cut_size);     //this question is about this step
        b = function(length - cut_size);
        if (a + b > current_max)
            current_max = a + b;
    }
    result[length] = current_max;
    return current_max;
}

int main() {

    int number_of_test_cases;
    int length_of_rod;

    cin>>number_of_test_cases;

    while (number_of_test_cases--)
    {
        cin>>length_of_rod;

        for (int i = 1; i <= length_of_rod; i++)
        {
            cin>>prices[i];
            result[i] = INT_MIN;
        }

        //profit of cutting rod to size 1
        result[1] = prices[1];

        cout<<function(length_of_rod)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Above, I have implemented the logic as explained in the book, except with a little modification which is what this post is about.

From the book,

```
1: let r[0..n] be a new array
2: r[0] = 0
3: for j = 1 to n
4:    q = -1
5:    for i = 1 to j
6:       q = max(q, p[i] + r[j-i])
7:    r[j] = q
8: return r[n]
```

p is the input array containing the profits for rod length going from 1 to n, and r is for storing the results.

Why on line 6 here is r[i] not being used instead of p[i], when r[i] already contains the best price that rod of length i can be sold for? It is possible that r[i] contains a higher value than p[i], implying that a rod of length i can fetch a higher price after being cut instead of being sold apiece. Of course, for the last run of the loop when i = j and the rod of length j is not being cut, it has to be p[i], because r[j] is the value that is being calculated and it doesn't exist yet. But i am confused about the other runs of the loop when the rod is being cut.

My solution uses the logic q = max(q, **r**[i] + r[j-i]) through these statements -

```
a = function(cut_size);
b = function(length - cut_size);
if (a + b > current_max)
    current_max = a + b;
```

If i modify it with a = prices[cut_size] according to the book, it is still successful on the OJ.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider `i` to be the length of the **last** piece you have cut (there is always going to be one, if you don't do any cut then the whole rod is the last piece). Since its a single piece, the profit you gain from this is `p[i]`. So what this approach is doing is trying for all possible **last** cut and using one that maximizes value.

Comment: Which is what I don't understand. Why not take into account the maximum profit that a rod can get with or without being cut instead of without being cut?

Comment: Because when you are on the last piece both values are same, so it doesn't matter what you choose. And there isn't any benefit of choosing one approach over another.

Comment: Yes, but the loop also runs for everything less than the last value, and for those values it could be more profitable to cut. This is why in my solution I took the last value out of the loop and ran the loop to check for r[i] instead of p[¡].